# How find a line that contains a regexp, and replace that line in a file on Android

Tags: android, replace, vi

I am trying to find a line in a file using regexp, and replace that line with a new line. I want to do this on the command line on Android.

I thought I could do it using vi like that:

```
vi +"%s/ro.streaming.video.drs.*/ro.streaming.video.drs=false/g | x" | build.prop
```

To replace line containing:

> ro.streaming.video.drs=true

with:

> ro.streaming.video.drs=false

However, I noticed that vi 1.1.6.1 in BusyBox doesn't support commands. Actually it doesn't really support much at all. Is there another way I can achieve the same thing on Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try BusyBox's `sed`?

```
sed -i 's/ro.streaming.video.drs.*/ro.streaming.video.drs=false/g' build.prop
```

Or even

```
sed -i '/ro.streaming.video.drs/ {s/=.*$/=false/}' build.prop
```

Comment: Will this keep text encoding, i.e. if file is UTF-8 will it still be UTF-8 after this operation?

Comment: I expect oldschool unix text utilities like `sed` to assume ISO-8859-1 (latin1) encoding. That said, the text you're changing is encoded the same way in ISO-8859-1 and in UTF-8, and I do expect `sed` to pass unmatched bytes as-is. I'd suggest testing it.